# How access the same extbase view from different controller actions in Typo3

Tags: typo3

The model is, to develop a Typo3 BE extension on extbase.

I only want to use one view with select boxes, text areas, ...
But if I call a specific action, Typo3 is expect a view with the same name.

```
public function xyzAction(array $extName = NULL) {
        error_log($extName['extList'][1]."-xlfAction-".$extName['search']);
        $xlfFiles = array();
        $xlfFiles[] = "Test2";
        $this->view->assign('xlfFiles', $xlfFiles);
        $this->redirect('init');
    }
```

`$this->view->assign(...)` tries to send the data to a xyz view. But I want to send the data to the init view, to where I redirect on the end.

What I need is a view object (replacement of $view) which assigned the data to the init view and not to the xyz view.

Or do you know a different solution?

I tried a lot of things, but nothing was working.
So what have I to do, to assign data to an different view?

Answer (score 1):

```
$arguments = [
  'arg1'  =>  $arg1,
  'arg2'  =>  $arg2
];
$this->redirectWithUriBuilder('actionName', 'controllerName', '', $arguments);
```

or you can also use `$this->redirect()`

https://typo3.org/api/typo3cms/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_extbase_1_1_mvc_1_1_controller_1_1_abstract_controller.html#afb75136221ebb5f62df87bb0be4a5108

Answer (score 1):

use `$this->forward`.

Maybe with `$this->forward('init', 'xlfFiles');` (not tested)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StandAloneView in your Controller.

```
/**
 * standaloneView
 *
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView
 * @inject
 */
protected $standaloneView = NULL;

/**
 * TypoScript configuration
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $ts = array();
```

You need to initialize it:

```
$this->ts = $this->configurationManager->getConfiguration(
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Configuration\ConfigurationManager::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FRAMEWORK, 
<your_ext_name_as_string>);

//set layout
$this->standaloneView->setLayoutRootPath(
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName(
$this->ts['view']['layoutRootPath']));

//set partials
$this->standaloneView->setPartialRootPath(
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName(
$this->ts['view']['partialRootPath']));

//Set extension and plugin name
$extensionName = $this->request->getControllerExtensionName();
$pluginName = $this->request->getPluginName();
$this->standaloneView->getRequest()->setControllerExtensionName($extensionName);
$this->standaloneView->getRequest()->setPluginName($pluginName);
```

And at the end you can "change" your view and set a different template name to be able to handle the other view.

```
$this->view = $this->standaloneView;

//Generate a new fileName
$newTemplateFileName = 
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::getFileAbsFileName(
$this->ts['view']['templateRootPath'] . 
(substr($this->ts['view']['templateRootPath'], -1) == '/' ? '' : '/') 
. '<Your_Folder>/<Your_File>.html');

//assign the new template file to the view.
$this->view->setTemplatePathAndFilename($newTemplateFileName);

//at this point you can assign values to your selected template
$this->view->assign('your_variable', $variable);
```

Comment: Finally I found the following solution:

Answer (score 0):

Fanally I found the following solution:

```
public function xyzAction(array $extName = NULL) {
    $xlfFiles = array();
    $xlfFiles[] = "Test2";
    $this->redirect('init', NULL, NULL, array('xlfFiles' => $xlfFiles));
}
```